# duda en autorización ruby on rails base de datos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hola es que tengo una duda es que necesito darle autorización a una tabla y nose como hacerlo es para darle autorización a unos snacks (que es comida) y nose como hacerlo y como estructurarlo, Si pasa la primera validación como autorizada sigue la segunda autorización. soy nuevo en este campo, gracias pór favor a ayuda.

esta una idea que tengo agredesco ejemplos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]